# Arduino is not handling this special turkish char

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide, non-ascii-characters

I am working on a project that includes Turkish characters. But I can't use one of this chars in a `if`.

Example:

```cpp
char myChar = 'ğ';
if(myChar == 'ğ'){
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A char variable can store 1 byte. Your Turkish character cannot be represented by a single byte. In UTF-8 encoding that's two bytes `C4 9F`.

use `char myChar[] = "ğ";` or `String myChar = "ğ";`

Read https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/UTF-8/